# Spring Boot ComandLinerRunner Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have a question

### Sample Class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.Sample.smartbuy" })
public class SmartBuyArtApi2ClientApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SmartBuyArtApi2ClientApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Entered the main app");
        SpringApplication.run(SmartBuyArtApi2ClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    public SmartBuyController cmartBuyController;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws SQLException {

        logger.info(" ********  Applications has started ******* ");

        logger.info(" cmartBuyController :: " + cmartBuyController.helloTest());

        logger.info(
                " *****************  cmartBuyController is not null ************* Arguments length :: " + args.length);

    }

}
```

### Controller

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:smartbuy.properties")
public class SmartBuyController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String helloTest() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

### Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@DataJpaTest
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class SmartBuyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private SmartBuyController cmartBuyControllerTest;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void postEntityTest() throws Exception {
        CommandLineRunner runner = ctx.getBean(SmartBuyArtApi2ClientApplication.class);
        runner.run();
    } 
}
```

If you look closely in main function cmartBuyController.helloTest() should print "Hello World" 
but i am getting null , Also the main Application is printing log twice in command line runner. 
Can any one please help how to execute these methods please.

Comment: Is your Test class annotated?

Comment: yes please , My test class is annotated with following      RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
ActiveProfiles("dev")
DataJpaTest
SpringBootTest

Comment: I have even created a sample method which returns String "Hello World" in component ( SampleTestComponents  ) even that returns null . Please help with any project explaining commandLinRunner testing as i can only see Web testing in spring

Comment: add your class and test class code with annotatitons

Comment: @drowny I have already annotated with following  RunWith(SpringRunner.class) ActiveProfiles("dev") DataJpaTest SpringBootTest . Can you please guide what annotations are missing please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it like this, it is working for me ;

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@SpringBootTest
class TestClass{

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void testRunMethod() {
        CommandLineRunner runner = ctx.getBean(CommandLineRunner.class);
        runner.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for help.. now i am able to start the test class and faced hiccup some other place.. Can you please help as i have updated my code .

Comment: is it logging any string? or your problem just about is printing null instead of Hello world?

Comment: Hi @drowny it is not logging anything , so the logger in main class is printing null

Comment: In short classes annotated with mock bean methods are not getting executed